# Looking for a free bulk/mass mailing software that can import addresses from csv

Tags: email, mailing-lists

Questions says it all really - I have a list of around 9000 email addresses that I'd like to mail a (html) newsletter to. I use Outlook 2007 at the moment, and it doesn't really handle this task very well (stops half way through if it finds an address with an error). It's important that it is able to import HTML pages as that's how I have the newsletter setup!

(Ideally I'd like a desktop software solution rather than online if possible!)

thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a web host (or you could use XAMP on windows) why not look at something like phplist (http://www.phplist.com/),  it works well for me, with 10,000 emails,  you just need to check your ISPs policies for the maximum emails per hour and set the throttling up correctly.

PhpList handles bounces and resends and if you install to a public host, subscription and un-subscription for your users.

Oh and it can load from a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'd rather keep to a desktop solution if possible, but it may come down to using an online solution

Comment: This can be set up on a desktop computer. It does not need to be "on the web," and--while phplist is intended to allow people to unsubscribe--does not absolutely require a web-exposed IP address or web-accessible computer for outbound mail to function. (WAMP = Windows Apache MySQL PHP) and it is all free (aside from windows). It does have the added benefit of not resending the first 4500 emails should there be an email address problem halfway through, since it tracks recipients.

Comment: As Horatio says you can install phplist on your windows PC,  which is why I suggested using XAMP to run it on your PC.  Remember though you will need to manually control the subscriptions un-subscriptions rather than letting PhpList do it.